# jQuery never calls .done() or .always() for ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having this simple get request:

```
   $.get('ri/i18n/locale')
      .done(function() {
        console.log(this);
      })
      .fail(function() {
        console.log(this);
      })
      .always(function(){
        console.log(this);
      });
```

Unfortunately none of the handlers are ever called.

I cann confirm that calling `ri/i18n/locale` in the browser returns a valid JSON string. I'm using jQuery 1.11.1 .

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Did you take a look at the web inspector / firebug? Maybe there is some problem with the request in the script.

Comment: It is working. Checkout here http://jsbin.com/kahone/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Maybe syntax error on the page, it never gets to AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be what version of jQuery you are using. Before jQuery 1.5, a `jqXHR` object was not returned with a `$.get()`, which is what allows you to use the promise behavior. [The relevant jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Answer (score 0):

After all I just missed the asynchronous nature of the ajax call. I had a breakpoint on all `console.log` statements and the statement following the ajax call. Since the the statement after the ajax call was hit first I assumed none of the `console.log` statements gets called.

Since I need the result of the ajax call to go on, I have to move all my code into the `done()` function.